# Refactoring js for multiple menus that are not siblings

Tags: jquery, menu, refactoring

I have created a header section that contains two menus that are not in the same ul. I would like the menu to open up the sub-menu on click and add a class (menu-open). Only one menu should be open at a time. I have achieved that using jQuery. However, I feel like it can be shorter or written better. I have researched this and people are using the sibling element. However, in my code the two uls for the menu are separate and are float to the edges of a div.

Here is my html:

```
<div>
 <ul class="menu-1 menu-btn">
  <li><a class="menu-link" href="">Menu 1</a>
    <ul class="sub-menu">
     <li>Item 1</li>
     <li>Item 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 <ul class="menu-2 menu-btn">
  <li>link1</li>
  <li>link2</li>
  <li><a class=menu-link href="">Menu 2</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li>Item 1</li>
    <li>Item 2</li>
   </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

This is my jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/8b8Lzm7v/10/

Any advice/help is appreciated. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is perhaps a little bit shorter but shouldn't have to get any longer should you add more menu's. Would suggest closing all menus and before opening the specific clicked menu after checking whether or not it's already open, optionally add another click handler to close all menu's if a non menu div is clicked...

```js
(function($) {

  function hideMenus() {
      $("ul.sub-menu").slideUp(100); // slide up all menus
      $(".menu-link").removeClass("menu-open"); // no menus are open
    } // hide all menu's as a function

  $(".menu-link").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      menuOpen = $this.hasClass("menu-open") || false;

    hideMenus();

    if (!menuOpen) { // if the menu is closed...
      $this.siblings('ul.sub-menu').slideDown(100); // this opens all .submenu's adjacent
      $this.addClass("menu-open");
    }
    return false;
  });

  $('body').not('.menu-btn').on('click', function() {
    hideMenus();
    return false;
  }); // optional to hide menu's if any other div is clicked

}(jQuery));
```

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
a {
  display: block;
}
.menu-btn {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
}
.menu-btn li {
  display: inline-block;
}
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.menu-1 .sub-menu {
  left: 0;
}
.menu-2 .sub-menu {
  right: 0;
}
.menu-2 {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="menu-1 menu-btn">
    <li><a class="menu-link" href="">Menu 1</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="menu-2 menu-btn">
    <li>link1</li>
    <li>link2</li>
    <li><a class=menu-link href="">Menu 2</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```